# Dynamically re-size RadSplitter to displayed panes

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, resize, splitter

Need to re-size the RadSplitter control on my WebUserControl to the total size of the displayed (not collapsed) panes.

For instance, I have 2 panes displayed within a RadSplitter. Each of these panes has a height of 250px. If one of these panes is collapsed, I only want the RadSplitter to take up space for 250px in height. If both panes are opened (none collapsed), I want the RadSplitter to take up space for 500px in height. This needs to be able to change in a live environment so that, if the user opens or closes a pane it makes the appropriate adjustments to the RadSplitter's height property.

Any idea's...?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is listed to the OnClientCollapsing event of the splitter and within it change the height of the main splitter div with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link:
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/initially-resize-the-radsplitter-according-to-its-content

They have good solution for this problem.